# Image to string text in C#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I wrote this code

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Now I want to check ms text. How can I do that?

Comment: MemoryStream doesnt have a Text property if that is what you are asking.  What would it say?

Comment: You cannot represents raw bytes as text directly. The only way is to encode it as base 64 encoded string. f.e `Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());`

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to display the image binary content as a string that can be copy/pasted and (for example) sent through e-mail?  Try Base64 encoding.

Comment: @nopeflow: Base64 is definitely not the "only" way but it is one of the most common.

Comment: @BenVoigt your are right -Base64 is one of the most and has bult-in implementation in c#.

Comment: @BenVoigt I got data stored in table as binary type and I have no clue if it is image text 
here's sample

0x255044462D312E350D25A6E9CFC40D0A312030206F626A0D3C3C2F436F6E74656E7473203439203020522F43726F70426F785B302E3020302E30203539352E323030303034203834312E36385D2F4D65646961426F785B302E3020302E30203539352E323030303034203834312E36385D2F506172656E742032203020522F5265736F75726365733C3C2F50726F635365745B2F5044462F546578742F496D616765422F496D616765432F496D616765495D2F584F626A6563743C3C2F496D30203438203020523E3E3E3E2F526F7461746520302F547970652F506167652F5061706572506F7274506167655469746C65

Comment: @nopeflow thanks it helped but my query not solved

Comment: @surya: That's hex, so you want to compare to a hex encoder like shown in Stefano's answer, not Base64 encoding.  Not sure but the database window might be showing the bytes in reverse order.

Comment: @BenVoigt I used same code it worked for while I am trying to convert image to hex code now I have some hex code, I want to convert to it in image but I am getting error

  HResult=-2146233033
  Message=Could not find any recognizable digits.
  Source=mscorlib

Comment: @BenVoigt
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
passing this hex code to convert in image

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show what is expected. Long comments are not readable.

Answer (score 1):

With this code, you can encode the image Bytes into an hexadecimal string representation:

```
Byte[] a = ms.ToArray();
String text = BitConverter.ToString(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code....

```
            var url = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/" + name);
            byte[] myByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(url);
           using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                ms.Write(myByte, 0, myByte.Length);
                i = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                System.Drawing.Image imageIn = i.GetThumbnailImage(100, 100,()=> false, IntPtr.Zero);
                imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                var storedUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                return storedUrl;
            }
```

Comment: Can you please add some descriptive context around what it is you are doing, and why you think this solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use this to send the image as string:

```
    string path = @"C:\Users\user6\Pictures\wp\tinypotato.jpg";
    string myString = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(path))
    Debug.WriteLine(myString); 
...
```

BR!